# In R, how to create a named list and a function of dynamically generated variables

Tags: r, list, function

I need a function of a (large) number of variables and a named list giving initial values for these variables. This is to use as input in the mle2 function in R.

Assign does not help me as I need to call the variables, not just give them values. I can create a list or vector with the names, but I cannot seem to get them recognized as variables.
I have tried the code below with and without get, tried the paste command directly in startlist and many other iterations like that.

```
    # This is an example with 4 variables that works:

    fun.long<-function(p1,p2,p3,p4) {
      p1+p2+p3+p4}

    startlist<-list(p1=0.5,p2=0.5,p3=0.5,p4=0.5)


    # Since I have way more than 4 variables I'd like to automate this.
    # what I had hoped for was something like:

    varname<-list()
    for (i in 1:4) {
    varname<-cbind(varname,paste0("p", i))}

    fun.long<-function(MyList) {
      q=0
      for (i in 1:4) {
        q=q+get(MyList[i])}
        return(q)}

    startlist<-list()
    for (i in 1:4) {
      startlist<-cbind(startlist,get(varname[i])=0.5)}
```

I would have liked `fun.long(varname)` to output `p1+p2+p3+p4` instead I get: `Error in get(varname[i]) : invalid first argument`

I would like the command `startlist` to print:

```
$p1
[1] 0.5

$p2
[1] 0.5

$p3
[1] 0.5

$p4
[1] 0.5
```

Instead I get:

```
Error: unexpected '=' in:
for (i in 1:4) {
  startlist<-cbind(startlist,get(varname[i])=
```

Comment: What about `library(magrittr);
rep(0.5, 4) %>% set_names(paste0("p", 1:4)) %>% as.list()`? (piping used to improve readability).

Comment: Do you need `do.call(sum, startlist)` or `Reduce("+", startlist)` ?

Comment: Does `vars <- paste0("p", 1:4); setNames(lapply(vars, get), vars)` work? If you want further generalization, then `vars <- ls(pattern = "^p[0-9]+$")` first.

Comment: Uwe: That solves the list creation problem!

Comment: Markus: mle2 wants a function as an input, so I need to define a function of a long list of variables that have not been assigned values.

Comment: r2evans: the setNames throws and error